# Float 'average' off by a hundredth

Tags: c#

**I'm doing this problem online: https://www.codewars.com/kata/getting-along-with-integer-partitions/train/csharp/5af1b2b768e64499ed000102**

The basic idea of it is that I'm supposed to find all the partions of a number and display the  range, average and median. The program handles most numbers fine, but while faced with some numbers, the average is not accurate.

These are some of the numbers I'm having trouble with:

- 43 --  Expected: Average: 202904.6**5**   But was: 202904.6**0**
- 36 -- Expected: Average: 26832.8**1**   But was:  Average: 26832.8**0**
- 41 --  Expected: Average: 113720.8**2**   But was:  Average: 113720.8**0**

**Is this because I'm using a float to store my numbers? If so, what datatype should I be using instead?**

Here's my code (You can paste it directly to the site I linked and it'll give you the same errors I'm having)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;

public class IntPart
{
    public static List<List<string>> listOfLists = new List<List<string>>();
    public static List<string> lastPartion = new List<string>(); //get the last partion

    public static string Part(long n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(n);
         lastPartion.Clear();
         listOfLists.Clear();

        List<List<long>> result = new List<List<long>>();
        partition((int)n);

        //gets rid of blip where there's an extra space at the start of the string and 
        foreach (var cycle in lastPartion)
            listOfLists.Add(cycle.Split(' ').ToList());

        //converts the cycles to a list and converts string list to double
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfLists.Count; i++)
        {
            listOfLists[i].RemoveAt(0);
            result.Add(listOfLists[i].Select(x => long.Parse(x)).ToList());
        }                

        return removeAndSort(result);
    }

    //partioning algorithom with recursion 
    public static void partition(int n)
    {
        partition(n, n, "");
    }
    public static void partition(int n, int max, string prefix)
    {
        if (n == 0)
        {
            lastPartion.Add(prefix);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = Math.Min(max, n); i >= 1; i--)
            partition(n - i, i, prefix + " " + i);
    }

    public static string removeAndSort(List<List<long>> listOfLists)
    {
        List<long> result = new List<long>();
        string resultString = "";

        //find the products
        foreach (var list in listOfLists)
        {
            long product = 1;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
                product *= list[i];

            result.Add(product);
        }

        //removes the duplicates
        result = result.Distinct().ToList(); //returns a copy of the list without any duplicates in the previous list
        result.Sort();

        int range = (int)(result.Max() - result.Min());
        float avg = (float)result.Sum() / (float)result.Count;
        float median = 0f;

        if (result.Count % 2 == 0)
            median = (float)Math.Round((double)((result[(result.Count / 2) - 1] + result[(result.Count / 2)])) / 2, 3);
        else
            median = result[result.Count / 2]; //odd

        return "Range: " + range + " Average: " + avg.ToString("0.00") + " Median: " + median.ToString("0.00");
    }

}
```

Comment: never mind, changed the float to a decimal and the numbers are fine.
any suggestions to make the code better would be nice though.

Comment: Actually, you're code is incredibly well formatted, especially for this being your first question on this site. So many other newcomers don't even format their code, let alone use bullets! My only comments would be, `listOfLists` could use a better name that describes what it does, maybe `partions`?, and the Microsoft commenting convention for C# is to do `// This` not `//this`. Just makes it easier to read, and to use `PascalCase` for nearly everything, except for local variables and paramters, they get `camelCase`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by the way `float` values are calculated. They are calculated in base 2, not base 10. When switching different bases, some numbers can't be represented in decimal form.

Famously, `1/3` can't be written as a decimal in base 10, but in base 12, `1/3` is `0.4` (and `1/2` is `0.6`).

Base 2 has trouble representing tenths. `0.1` ends up being `0b00110011` repeating, or something like that.

`decimal` in C# calculates in base ten, not base two. This makes it more accurate and better for money, however it is slower to some degree